# Set IP Address based on User Name

Tags: windows-7, networking, script, ip

So I have a script from my old XP installation that sets the IP address based on what the username is. Here is the script:

```
'Get Username
set objNetwork = wscript.CreateObject("wscritp.network")
User=objNetwork.Username


'Set IP address based on username
Select Case User
    Case "user1"
        arrIPAddress = Array("192.168.1.9")
    Case "user2"
        arrIPAddress = Array("192.168.1.10")
    Case "user3"
        arrIPAddress = Array("192.168.1.11")
    Case "user4"
        arrIPAddress = Array("192.168.1.12")
    Case "user5"
        arrIPAddress = Array("192.168.1.13")
End Select

'non-changing values
arrSubnetMask = Array("255.255.255.0")
'arrGateway = Array("192.168.1.1")    
'arrGatewayMetric = Array(1)

'Below obtained from MSDN site WMI Tasks: Networking, slightly modified
strComputer = "."
setobjWMIService = GetObject _
    ("winmgmts:\\ " & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

set colNetAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where ipenabled = rue")

for each objNetAdapter in colNetAdapters
    errEnable = objNetAdapter.EnableStatic(arrIPAddress, arrSubnetMask)

Next

set ipconfigset = objwmiservice.execquery _
    ("select IPAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where ipenabled = true")

for each ipconfig in ipconfigset
    if not isnull(ipconfig.ipaddress) then
        for i=lbound(ipconfig.ipaddress) _
            to unbound(ipconfig.ipaddress)
                wscript.echo "Logged in as " & User & ", IP Address: " & ipconfig.ipaddress(i)

        next
    end if
next
```

This script works 100% on an XP machine. However whenever I move it to Windows 7 it doesn't do anything at all. I've placed it in the iplogon folder for group policy as well as the startup folder. Was there a big syntax change between XP and 7?

Comment: If you run it manually on a Windows 7 machine does it work? How about if you Run it "as Administrator"?  Have you stepped through it with a VBA debugger to see how it runs?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't include as much information as I should have.

I've run it manually and nothing happens. I'm running it on an administrator level account so it should automatically run as administrator, but I went to go and set "run as administrator" and the option isn't there on the right-click menu or under properties.

Comment: What if you run a command prompt as admin and then run the script from inside that?

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that the syntax could've been majorly changed. You have to remember that windows 7 brought many changes in terms of speed about. Take a look at your error logs to see how well the script runs and if it seems to not notice something or runs a different command then that is the issue. Also, I recall alot of 'updates' pertaining to the actual network connection commands however, that may be my rig alone.